# Binding to 'style.grid' throws 'sanitizing unsafe style value' warning

Tags: css, typescript, angular5, css-grid

I'm creating a mechanism for defining and calculating my own reusable grids.  Here's an example of what's returned

> [left-bleed-start] 10.245000000001024px [left-bleed-end content-col-start] 1331.8500000001332px [content-col-end right-bleed-start] 10.245000000001024px [right-bleed-end]/[top-bleed-start] 10.245000000001024px [top-bleed-end link-row-start] 81.9600000000082px [content-row-end footer-row-start] 163.9200000000164px [footer-row-end bottom-bleed-start] 10.245000000001024px [bottom-bleed-end]

When applying it like this

```
<div class="appCompGrid" [style.grid]="Grid.GridCode"></div>
```

I get the santization warning.  However if I copy and paste the value in like this

```
<div class="appCompGrid" style="grid: (same code);"></div>
```

everything works.  The  css class is where I define the display as grid seeing that it'll be consistent no matter what size the screen is.  The only thing I could think to do was go back into the function and add `+ ';'` to the end of where the grid code is put together figuring maybe that was throwing something off but it still gives the same error.  I tried applying `display: grid;` inline to see if maybe there was a problem with it reading both from a css class and inline for some odd reason.

I'm using `@HostListener` to re-calculate the grid as the size or orientation changes, so far I haven't run into a problem with Angular functioning in this manner so I don't understand where to begin with figuring out why this is happening.  Here's how I have my  component classes set up.

Base Class

```
export class GridBuilder {
    Settings : GridInit        = new GridInit();
    GridData : Array<GridType> = new Array();
    Grid     : GridOutput      = new GridOutput();


    constructor() { this.GridData = GridDefs; }

    public buildGrid() {
        const coreSettings : GridInit   = this.Settings;
        const gridData     : GridType[] = this.GridData;

        const w: number     = multiply( coreSettings.Size.Width,  coreSettings.Size.PixelRatio );
        const h: number     = multiply( coreSettings.Size.Height, coreSettings.Size.PixelRatio );
        const o: string     = checkOrientation( w, h );
        const c: CellSpecs  = calcCell( o, w );
        const t: GridType   = gridData.find( a => a.GridName == coreSettings.GridStyle );

        const cols: string  = calcArea( t.Columns, c );
        const rows: string  = calcArea( t.Rows, c );

        this.Grid.GridCode  = cols + '/' + rows + ';';
        this.Grid.GridAreas = t.Areas;
    }
}
```

Secondary class for app component/ any top tier container

```
export class SiteGrid extends GridBuilder {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.applySizeSettings();
    }

    applySizeSettings(){
        this.Settings.Size.Width       = window.innerWidth;
        this.Settings.Size.Height      = window.innerHeight;
        this.Settings.Size.PixelRatio  = window.devicePixelRatio;
    }
}
```

the AppComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent extends SiteGrid {
    title = 'app';

    @HostListener( 'window: resize', [ '$event' ] )onResize( event ){ this.applySizeSettings(); this.buildGrid(); }

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.Settings.GridStyle = 'SiteGridA';
        this.buildGrid();
    }
}
```

I don't know how relevant this may be in helping figure out the solution but thought I'd show how things are flowing just incase.  Anyone know why this warning is occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a sanitizer to cleanse your css, or bypass it...

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.sanitizedCSS = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(Grid.GridCode) ;
  }
```

As for why, this [blog](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-security-the-domsanitizer-service-2202c83bd90) explains it pretty well, as does the [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) documentation.

> DomSanitizer helps preventing Cross Site Scripting Security bugs (XSS) by sanitizing values to be safe to use in the different DOM contexts.

Comment: splendid.  I just read the blog.  I take it by the `this.sanitizedCSS` in your answer means I have to create another variable to pass it into and bind to that in my template?

Comment: @Optiq that is correct, bind to sanitizedCSS and you should be sailing.! Sanitization is a hotly debated topic on the angular GitHub, it's very important as it protects the user, but it is annoying to implement. You will also need to do this if you bind to `<img src`

Comment: ok I'm having some trouble with this.  Does the variable have to be named `sanitizedCSS`?  I made a new one and gave it the same type as the type for `Grid` and tried to pass the whole object and I seen where I bound the json that it says `changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity`.  Plus the style isn't showing up in the inspector.

Comment: ok I see I have to do it one value at a time.  Which may need asking another question considering the other body of css.

Comment: @Optiq Yeah, you can just loop it and then *ngFor maybe - it's a complete annoyance haha

Comment: I was just thinking to see if I can set the property through `nativeElement` somehow if it became too much of a problem lol.

Comment: @Optiq A side note, you might actually not have to sanitize if you use `[ngStyle]"={'grid': Grid.GridCode}"` (I can't remember if that's true though and I can't test right now)

Comment: Yeah I might explore that route as well because I have another object inside that object that defines its' parameters like this `export class StringList { [ key:string ]: string; }`, so none of the properties will ever be the same name, seems a bit complicated to sanitize dynamically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160828/discussion-between-optiq-and-zze).